# Html code validation problems

Tags: html, css, validation

I am facing problem with html code validation. My code is like:

```
 `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">

           <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
         Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
     </head>

     <body>
        <!---this is a comment----->
    </body>
</html>`
```

It shows me an error. The error code is :

> Consecutive hyphens did not terminate a comment. -- is not permitted inside a comment, but e.g. - - is.

what was the problem in my comment?? Please help

Comment: <!---this is a comment-----> should be <!-- this is a comment -->

Comment: How do you validate the HTML-Markup?

Comment: This is so difficult to search for an `--$` insteed of `--`... but spec is a spec.

Comment: Thank you all  for commenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple dashes, this causes the HTML parser to think that the comment has ended, so it starts looking for a `>` which it cannot find.

So, when using comments, just use two dashed before and after, and never use two dashes in a row in the comment text itself.

This is formally not allowed, [according to the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#comments):

> 4.7. Comments # T
>
> Comments consist of the following parts, in exactly the following order:
>
> - the *comment start delimiter* `"<!--"`
> - text
> - the *comment end delimiter* `"-->"`
>
> The text part of comments has the following restrictions:
>
> - must not start with a ">" character
> - must not start with the string "->"
> - **must not contain the string "--"**
> - **must not end with a "-" character**
>
> The following is an example of a comment.
>
> ```
> <!-- main content starts here -->
> ```

Your comment violates both the rules that I made bold.

Comment: Thank you @GolezTrol. I did not know the rules of commenting. Thank you so much.